# Not updating store is still showing empty react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to build an app with react-redux but when m fetching a data async using api than data is coming but state and store is not updating please help..
here is my 
**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from './store/configurestore'
import AppRouter from './routers/Approuter'
import {fetchReports} from './actions/reports'
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const store = configureStore();
const state = store.getState();

const AppRoute = (

<Provider store={store}>
<AppRouter/>
</Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(<p>Loading...</p>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
store.dispatch(fetchReports(state)).then(()=> {
    console.log(store.getState())
    ReactDOM.render(AppRoute, document.getElementById('root'));
    registerServiceWorker();
})
```

**reports.js(action file)** this is my action file in which i am doing my async action

```
export const addReport = (reports) => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_REPORT',
        reports
    }    
}

export const saveReports = (reportData = {}) => {
    return dispatch => {
        const {
            r_id=0,
            reg_date ='',
            reg_no = 0,
            patient_name ='',
            gender ='',
            age = 0,
            mobile_number = '',
            email_id = '',
            refer_by = '',
            test_request = '',
            report_status = '',
            total_amt = 0,
            receipt_amt = 0,
            bal_amt = 0 
        } = reportData
        const reports = {r_id, reg_date, reg_no, patient_name, gender, age, mobile_number , email_id , refer_by, test_request , report_status , total_amt, receipt_amt, bal_amt}

        return fetch('http://localhost/aruna/addreport.php',{
            method:'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(reportData)
        }).then(reportData => dispatch(addReport(reportData.reports))
    )}
}

export const setReports = (reports) => {
    return {
        type:'SET_REPORTS',
        reports
    }
}

export const fetchReports = () => {
        return (dispatch) => {
           return fetch('http://localhost/aruna/getreports.php').then((response) =>{
            const reports = [];
            Object.keys(response).forEach((report) => {
                reports.push({
                   r_id:report.key,
                 ...report 
                })
            })
            dispatch(setReports(reports))
           })
}
}
```

this my reducer file

```js
const reportsDefaultstate = []

export default (state=reportsDefaultstate, action ) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case 'ADD_REPORT':
            return [
                ...state,
                action.reports
            ]
        case 'SET_REPORTS':
            return action.reports
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

my **configureStore.js** file

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import reportsReducer from '../reducers/reportreducer'
import filterReducer from '../reducers/filterreducer'


export default () => {
    const store = createStore(
        combineReducers({
            reports: reportsReducer,
            filters: filterReducer
        }),
        composeWithDevTools(
            applyMiddleware(thunk)
        )

    )
    return store;
}
```

how can i update store or state with that fetched data here. Please help me to figure the error in this code

Comment: What is `configureStore` ? Can you show the code?

Comment: Can you update a question? instead of put it as a comment?

Comment: this my **configureStore.js**  file

Comment: the Reason i updated my question you can check it out

Comment: Are you really sure that `store.dispatch` returns a Promise object?

Comment: yes it will return promise

Comment: Try to add a catch to the promise, maybe is failing for some reason

Comment: showing nothing is there any problem in this code becoz of that its not working